# Knockout DateTime Picker - Default Date not Binding

Tags: datetime, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am using this Bootstrap DateTime Picker: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

I have created a Custom Binder for DateTime called datepicker:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'};
        $(element).datetimepicker(options);

        //when a user changes the date, update the view model
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "dp.change", function(event) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
                value(event.date);
            }
        });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor)   {
        var widget = $(element).data("datepicker");
        //when the view model is updated, update the widget
        if (widget) {
            widget.date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            if (widget.date) {
                widget.setValue();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And I My Model is in JSON, as I am converting C# dateTime to JSON I get this Date: `"/Date(1427368178393)/"`

```
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Quote Date</label>
                    <div class='input-group date dateTimes'>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="datepicker: QuoteDateTime" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

But the Problem is that the first time the Page Loads even though the QuoteDateTime has a value it is not showing in the DateTimePicker.

Here is the JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mdawood1991/ezv7qxbt/

I need the First Value to Show in the DateTime Picker.

**EDIT**

The thing is that my ViewModel has a List of Accommodations

This is the Console Log of my viewModel

[image]

I could convert every dateTime to a moment as you suggester, but then I shouldn't use the knockout Mapping Plugin: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Is this the only solution to loop through my viewModel and then converting alld Datetimes to a moment object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After help From @David and @Bryant I changed my code to update viewModel with moment object date.

The Problem was that the Date was only posting back correctly after selecting a Date from the DateTime Picker. So I changed code so when Initialized I update the viewModel. And it is working now.

This is the DateTime Picker

http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

I used the following datepicker binding.

JSFiddle Working: http://jsfiddle.net/mdawood1991/cL9k2sbe/

My Solution:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = {
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
            defaultDate: valueAccessor()()
        };

        if (allBindingsAccessor() !== undefined) {
            if (allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions !== undefined) {
                options.format = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions.format !== undefined ? allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions.format : options.format;
            }
        }

        $(element).datetimepicker(options);

        //when a user changes the date, update the view model
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "dp.change", function (event) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
                value(event.date);
            }
        });

        var defaultVal = $(element).val();
        var value = valueAccessor();
        value(moment(defaultVal, options.format));
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var thisFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm';

        if (allBindingsAccessor() !== undefined) {
            if (allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions !== undefined) {
                thisFormat = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions.format !== undefined ? allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions.format : thisFormat;
            }
        }

        var value = valueAccessor();
        var unwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value());

        if (unwrapped === undefined || unwrapped === null) {
            element.value = new moment(new Date());
            console.log("undefined");
        } else {
            element.value = unwrapped.format(thisFormat);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Your update function doesn't work at all. Making it work will fix your issue and cause updates to the observable to be reflected in the control.

1. Use `$(element).data("DateTimePicker")`
2. Convert the date string to a moment.js object
3. Pass it in using `date()` function.

Code:

```
update: function(element, valueAccessor)   {
    var widget = $(element).data("DateTimePicker");

    if (widget) {
        var date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        if (typeof date === "string") {
            // convert c# string to momentjs object
            date = moment(date);
        }

        widget.date(date);
    }
}
```

**Edit -- Option 2: Keep everything as a moment.js object**

An issue with your code however is that a string is passed into the observable, but whenever this custom binding updates that observable it makes it a moment.js object (`input -> string` and `output -> Moment`). To fix this, I would recommend having the user pass in a moment.js object to the observable (`input -> Moment` and `output -> Moment`).

First, convert your c# string to a moment.js object when you fill your view model:

```
self.QuoteDateTime = ko.observable(moment(data.QuoteDateTime));
```

Second, change your update function to handle moment.js objects instead of strings:

```
update: function(element, valueAccessor)   {
    var widget = $(element).data("DateTimePicker");
    //when the view model is updated, update the widget
    if (widget) {
        var date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        widget.date(date);
    }
}
```

You can see this working just fine in this jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ezv7qxbt/21/

Comment: By the way, you will also want to change your change event handler to set the knockout observable as a string in the format `/Date(1427368178393)/` (that way it's consistent, but personally I would change it to make the input and output a Date object)

Comment: @DawoodAwan see my update and working example (I realized you have moment.js here so it's better to use that).

Comment: @BryantMiano haha, that's fine.

Comment: David's method is much cleaner than my answer.  Using moment.js is the way to go.

Comment: @DavidSherret the thing is that I have an Array of Accommodations which have a DateTime against them, Then I will have to loop through my viewModel each time Ajax request is sent. See my EDIT in Question

Comment: @DawoodAwan then just change it when you initialize your viewmodel. `self.QuoteDateTime = ko.observable(moment(data.QuoteDateTime));`

Comment: Is that possible using  ko.mapping.fromJS() ? I can't find it in the Documentation. Or do I have to create mappings manually for this to work

Comment: @DawoodAwan ah, i see now. I think it's possible. See the [`Customizing object construction using "create"`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) section.

Comment: Thanks for the help @DavidSherret , I was able to convert the ViewModel to moment in the init method of the datepicker binder: https://jsfiddle.net/mdawood1991/cL9k2sbe/

Comment: @DawoodAwan updating the observable still doesn't update the object in your code: https://jsfiddle.net/cL9k2sbe/1/ (change the date and then hit reset. It won't work properly) -- I don't like this way of doing things, but if you really want to convert the string to a moment object in the custom binding then you can do the following: https://jsfiddle.net/cL9k2sbe/5/

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the [default date option.](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#defaultdate)

```
var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
                defaultDate: valueAccessor()()
            };
```

Updated JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3jqL8s1m/

Comment: Cheers. That's what I was missing

Comment: This doesn't post the correct dateTime to the Server. It is posting 01/01/0001 If you don't select a Date