# Issue with Binding JQuery-UI Calendar Control with Date Populated

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, calendar

I'm having issues with binding the calendar control based on jquery-UI.
I'm using Knockout and REST API to get the date value and it gets populated correctly in the input text box as below, but the calendar does not reflect the correct binding with the date populated? What needs to be done to reflect the correct date in the calendar.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="LaunchDate">Launch Date</label>
<div class="input-group"                 
 <input type="text" data-bind="value: Launch_Date"  class="date-picker form-control input-sm" id="LaunchDate"/>
<label for="LaunchDate" class="input-group-addon btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> </label>
</div>
</div>
```

Knockout JS Code:
    self.Launch_Date = ko.observable(moment.utc(data.d.Launch_Date).format("YYYY-MMM-DD"));

DatePicker Code JQuery UI and Bootstrap:
        $(".date-picker").datepicker();

Comment: consider using knockout custom binding

Comment: yes, i tried using the following custom KO Binder, it didn't work for me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283815/knockout-datetime-picker-default-date-not-binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the dateFormat option. The format the picker is set to use should match the format of the date you're initializing it with.

```
$(".date-picker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
```

EDIT: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wnhs8rnb/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This has resolved my issue. It works perfectly fine with the dateFormat option. Everyone was asking me to use Custom KO Binder for JQuery UI Datepicker. Not sure when to use that?

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are getting the value from data.d.Launch_Date.Some time REST api with json returns the date value with backslash, and you need to parse it,
var dt = new Date(parseInt(data.d.LaunchDate) and then you can try this format 'MM/DD/YYYY' instead of using the MMM.